# require vs include in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I was trying to understand the difference between 'require' and 'include' keywords in yocto.

The major difference is that 'require' will throw an error when it doesn't find that file.

To test that
1. I created a recipe using recipetool
2. Then added a line 'include test.inc' in the recipe. The file doesnt exist. It still gave me the error.

[image]

Comment: please do not screenshot terminal window; this is literally just a text you can copy and paste here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is certainly misleading but what it's trying to tell you is "don't use quotes". This should work as you expected:

```
include test.inc
```